# Original Einstein papers on theory of relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, specific-reference

I am looking for definitive way to get einstein original paper on theory of relativity which is both papers of special relativity and general relativity. I am software engineer with graduation in engineering and not physics student or relevant researcher though I am thinking of studying this. I will like to know what are websites for physics study and how to get original papers in english? I should explain why I am asking this because just one search can give some sites that can give those papers but there are official physics institutes with websites that should give it. I am in computer networking and we have ieee origanisation and ietf that gives standards and rfcs. I am looking on same line what are internet resources to get original physics papers.

Comment: Two minutes with Google brings this. https://guides.loc.gov/einstein-annus-mirabilis/1905-papers  You can probably find PDFs of many of these papers.

Comment: And https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/

Comment: Einstein’s papers are certainly of great historical interest, but in my opinion they aren’t the best way to learn either Special Relativity or General Relativity. More than a century later, there are much better expositions.

Comment: I echo @Ghoster comment. If you want to learn relativity get a modern treatment. The seminal works are almost never the best place to learn anything

Comment: When physicists or researchers publish their papers, where do they get published and archived officially by any well known institute or organisation?

Comment: Wikipedia has a long [list of physics journals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_physics_journals). The library of a decent university will have a subscription to the top journals. It’s common to publish a preprint on [arXiv.org](https://arxiv.org/) before the paper appears in a journal; you can read these without any kind of subscription. By the time a paper gets published, it is “old news”; researchers today mainly learn about the latest research from preprints.

Comment: I would say that most research physicists tend to be more interested in current, cutting-edge research than in original papers from 100 or 200 years ago. (You can learn established physics better from modern textbooks.) However, with physicists as important as Einstein, their collected works are sometimes available online, as with the Princeton site.

Comment: Some of the most prestigious physics journals are published by the American Physical Society. An online subscription may be worth considering if you are serious about physics. For example, you could buy access to the [Physical Review Online Archive](https://journals.aps.org/about/prola) going back to 1893. Physical societies in other countries probably have similar offerings for their journals.

Comment: thanks for your inputs. I understand there is no single source to get physics research papers and also it depends on what subject it refers in physics as well. I also like to add original paper of Einstein is in german language and I will have to go for english version to search.